# How to convert error value from shorthand notation to standard form

Tags: python

In shorthand error notation, a value and its respective error are shown as

```
value(error)
```

Where error denotes the error in the last digits of value. For example

```
12345.67(89) == 12345.67 +/- 0.89
1234.5(6789) == 1234.5 +/- 678.9
```

In the second example, there is error in the last 4 digits of 1234.5, and since we there is one digit after the decimal point, 6789 will also have the same form.
My current solution works but seems inefficient in its execution, especially when parsing large datasets.

```
value = 12345.67
error =78

print(f'Result = {value}({error})')
if '.' in str(value): # Check for decimal point  
    decimals = str(value).split('.')[1] #capture the numbers following the decimal place
    dec_len = len(decimals) # how many digits after the decimal point 
    error = error / (10**dec_len) # divide error by 10^number_of_decimals
# If no decimal point, the error is absolute 12345.6(789)=12345.6+/-789
print('This is equivalent to:')
print(f'Result = {value}+/-{error}')
```

Comment: How does `(89)` mean `+/- 0.89` (divide by 100) but `(6789)` means `+/- 678.9` (divide by 10)? Which is it? What does this have to do with relative and absolute errors? Relative errors are specified as a % of the nominal value. Absolute errors are specified as an absolute value. Your code doesn't seem to do anything to convert a percentage to an absolute value.

Comment: It has nothing to do with %. I guess the use of the word relative is misleading. The error value is relative to the precision of the actual value.  The number of digits in the error is equal in magnitude to the final x number digits of the actual value. This is an error conversion used in the nuclear physics community and I am trying to convert from that format to the more standardised format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to an integer to string and manipulating that is slow. It's faster to iteratively multiply a number until it's whole.

```
def convert_error(value, error):
    decimals = 0
    while value != int(value):
        value *= 10
        decimals += 1
    return error / 10**decimals
```

This is an order of magnitude improvement of your method according to my timings.